# Display PowerPoint slides on machines that don't have Office

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint presentation.

I want to make sure that my PowerPoint slides will even work on machines that don't have 
Office. I have saved my presentation as PowerPointShow (`*.ppsx`), but I am not sure if I am doing it the right way.

I don't want to edit my presentation file, I just want to make sure that user is able to see the presentation slides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider saving your presentation as a PDF file if you don't care about the animations. I always do this because PDF format is highly portable and compatible. Any PDF reader can display your file. You can save your presentation file as PDF using [2007 Microsoft Office Add-in: Microsoft Save as PDF or XPS](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=4d951911-3e7e-4ae6-b059-a2e79ed87041&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 1):

You will need Microsoft Office to make use of your PowerPoint presentation, wherever you go. There are OpenSource alternatives to Microsoft Office such as OpenOffice that would be able to open the file but I am unsure of the compatibility.

You may want to take a look at Office Web Apps http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/web-apps/. If you can get your presentation working using the Web App you can run it from anywhere with an internet connection.

Comment: So, I even wont be able to view my files?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to save your presentation as PDF, make sure PDF reader is available on the machine.

You can also save all slides as images (jpg, png).

You can also use http://www.slideshare.net/ to upload presentation and access on destination machine if internet is available on it.